# Get one Wordpress JetPack call instead of two in Ember js without Ember Data

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ember.js, jetpack

I am an ember beginner and created a test  without Ember Data for the WordPress JetPack json API:  http://broerse.net/ember/wp3/#/posts (resulting in one JetPack call)

If you access a post via an URL like http://broerse.net/ember/wp3/#/posts/3787  I don’t know how to return a post with an ‘id’ from the objects created with findAll. I ended up fetching the specific post by ‘id’ from JetPack again. Is there a way to rewrite ‘find’ in the code below so there is no need for two JetPack call’s?

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});

App.Post = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Post.reopenClass({
  findAll: function() {
    return Ember.$.ajax({ url: 'http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/58826716/posts/?number=10', dataType: "jsonp", type: 'GET' }).then(function(data) {
      return data.posts.map(function(post) {
        post['id'] = post['ID'];
        delete post['ID']; 
        return App.Post.create(post);
      });
    });
  },

  find: function(id) {
    return Ember.$.ajax({ url: 'http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/58826716/posts/' + id + '/', dataType: "jsonp", type: 'GET' }).then(function(post) {
      post['id'] = post['ID'];
      delete post['ID']; 
      return App.Post.create(post);
    });
  }

});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.findAll();
  }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PostRoute` can be modified to look for the post in the model already loaded by the `PostsRoute`. If found will return it, otherwise will try to loaded it through the ajax call.

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var post = this.modelFor("posts").findBy("id",parseInt(params.post_id)); 
    if(Em.isEmpty(post)){
      return App.Post.find(params.post_id);    
    }else{
      return post;
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exact what I was looking for. Working [demo](http://broerse.net/ember/wp4/#/posts/3787)

Comment: Is the parseInt really needed? Why?

Comment: @Martin Broerse I used it because the param was not an integer for findBy "id" to function correctly .If you tried without it and it works, then fine.

Comment: it does not work without the parseInt but for me that is not clear from the Ember documentation.